# How making current_date fuction in preperedstatement in mysql using java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
Connection connec = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

String currDate="current_date";
pstmt = connec.preparedStatement("select id from patient where date=?"); pstmt.setString(1,currDate);
```

It returns `00-00-0000`
Why ?

Comment: ```pstmt.executeQuery()``` have you tried this?

Comment: Yes of course .. ResultSet rset=pstmt.executeQuery();

Comment: Try to set the date inside ```setString``` like ```(1, "1,1,2020")```  and see the output.

Comment: *"Why ?"* Because the `date` columns value is not equal to the **text literal** `'current_date'`. Instead, use `pstmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()));`

Comment: what is the datatype for date in the table?

Comment: Andreas : i understood ur reponse and it woooorks ! ... thaaank u very muuch ! :) :) :)

Comment: Or you need to use `where date=current_date` in the query itself.

Comment: @Andreas It is probably better to use `setObject(1, LocalDate.now())` (assuming a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't like to assume. My version works with Java8 and any JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

```
        try {
        connec=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/essaiscle","root","");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        String currDate="CURRENT_DATE();";
        pstmt=connec.prepareStatement("SELECT id from essaisdate WHERE date1=?");
        pstmt.setString(1,currDate);

        rset=pstmt.executeQuery();

        DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
        while(rset.next()){
        String myDate=df.format(rset.getDate(1));

         model.addRow(new Object[]{myDate} );
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```